# Changes done with file i/o are not visible

Tags: unix, transactions, io

I have a python script that opens a file and writes bunch of stuff then closes it. I run this python file by connecting to ssh. On the other side I have another ssh terminal connected to the same machine and I want to monitor the changes/writes to the file by the running script. However, when I do cat "file_name" or something like that the file seems to be empty. Only after the script terminates, I see the stuff.

First of all is this something related to atomicity properties of transactions ?

Second, is there anyway to achieve monitoring my file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big is your file?

If it is small (for some vague definition of small, but probably under 4 KiB), then the chances are that your Python script is buffering the changes it's making in memory, and only writing to disk when you close the file.

If your file is large (say, bigger than 64 KiB), then this won't be the explanation.  At intermediate sizes, it is relatively unlikely to be the explanation; at truly small sizes like 1 KiB or less, it is very plausible.

Consider looking for ways to flush file changes, or memory mapping files.

Comment: Thanks this was the case and creating an unbuffered file by using  f = open( FileName, 'a', 0 ) instead of  f = open( tmpLogFileName, 'a') solved the problem. Thanks!